# Stupid sql error

Tags: sql, android, sqlite

I have this sql statement:

```
SELECT game.game_id FROM game, userGame WHERE userGame.user_id = 1
AND userGame.game_id != game.game_id;
```

And I'm getting this:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5
```

I'm running the statement on a Sqlite3 database on Android 2.1.

The tables are:

```
USERGAME
--------
userId
gameId
more_columns

GAME
-----
gameId
more_columns
```

How can I solve this error?

**UPDATE:**
I want to get all game's id that they are not in usergame table when userId=1.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using != in your join?

Comment: It's only an error if it's not doing what you expect. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: So, for a given user (userID = 1), you want to retrieve all the games they DON'T have. Is that correct?

Comment: @XSaint32: yes, it's correct. Sorry for my english. Say what I think in English is so hard for me.

Comment: @Vans - I thought that's what you meant ;) See my answer below if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exists syntax:

```
select gameID
from game g
where not exists
(select null from usergame ug 
 where g.gameID = ug.gameID and ug.userID = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Sqlite syntax, but you can try something like this. Maybe someone else can straighten out the syntax?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    game a left outer join usergame b on a.gameId = b.gameId and b.userId = 1
WHERE   b.gameId IS NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT  *
FROM    game a, usergame b
WHERE   (a.gameId *= b.gameId AND b.userId = 1)
        AND b.gameId IS NULL
```

Basically, you're saying: "Give me all the games in the [game] table, but exclude the ones that userID 1 has."

I'm not sure if that's what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: `*=` is pre-ANSI-92 SQL Server specific OUTER JOIN syntax, no?

Comment: @OMG Ponies - It probably is. However, as I am unfamiliar with SQLite syntax, I provided only what I have known to work in T-SQL. I barely use *= myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT game_id 
  FROM game a  
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1 
                     from game b, userGame c 
                    where a.game_id=b.game_id and b.game_id=c.game_id and c.user_id=1)
```